# JavaScript equivalent to composer

Tags: javascript, package-management

Is there a package dependency manager such as composer, but for JavaScript files. I want to use my js files that are in one project (one repository) in another project (another repository)

What do you suggest to use?

Comment: Not sure, but [require.js](http://requirejs.org/) ?

Answer (score 1):

try https://yarnpkg.com

- you have packages.json like composer.json
- you have CLI commands like composer
- you have yarn.lock like composer.lock

https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/usage